# How to generate unique value every time program runs.

Tags: php

I have to generate 20 unique six character long promotion code. I am following code to generate them which are then csv generated. Now, if run my program again it should not generate already generated 'promotion code'. How can I prevent it. I am not using any database for the storage. This is the code that I tried to generate the promotion code.

```
$conn = new Promotion();
$coupons= $conn->generateCodes();


class Promotion{
    public function randomString(){
        $uc    = ['Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M'];
        $lc    = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm'];
        $num      = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

        $char  = [];
        $promotionCode = '';

        $char = array_merge($char, $num, $uc, $lc);

        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
            $promotionCode .= $char[mt_rand(0, count($char) - 1)];
        }
        return $promotionCode;

    }

    public function generateCodes(){
        $promoCodes = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < 250; $i++) {
            $temp = $this->randomString();
            $promoCodes[] = $temp;
        }
        return $promoCodes;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.com-create-guid.php

Comment: If these are promotion codes, don't you need to either keep track of them anyway, or generate them according to a particular scheme which is not just six random characters as above, such that they can be verified? If not, can't someone just enter any random string as a promotion code?

Comment: https://github.com/joashp/simple-php-coupon-code-generator

Comment: @tremby it will be stored as a csv files.

Comment: Then you could use the first part of my answer below; when generating load the CSV file and ensure you're not repeating any of the codes already there. But beware: if you create a lot of codes this will get slow! To mitigate that you could cache them in a hashmap-like structure, like a set in redis.

Answer (score 4):

You're either going to have to store codes you've already generated, and when generating a new one ensure it's not one you've already used, or you're going to have to change your scheme to be based on the current time in such a way that a code generated with a later time cannot possibly give the same code again.

But if your random string is long enough and random enough, the chances of generating the same one again becomes vanishingly small, so you'll have to consider whether either approach is worth the effort.

Comment: Agree, and six characters seems to be insufficient to fulfill the last section of this answer.

Comment: Would I be right in saying that with an alphabet of length 62, and six characters, there are 62^6 possible codes? That'd be 56800235584 possibilities. So I'd say it depends how many codes you're going to generate.

Comment: It really depends on how unlucky you are :)